# When loading WebView with html code, when exactly is the result rendered?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I am loading my html to `WebView` using `loadDataWithBaseURL`. I am setting `webViewClient` for the `WebView` object, and in its `onPageCommitVisible` function, trying to convert the result - loaded page - to bitmap.

But sometimes, this callback is invoked too early - function `measure` and the following `measuredHeight` is zero - in such case I need to wait some time and repeat the measurement later. What is the correct place, in `WebView`, where the html is already loaded and I can measure its rendered height?

```
override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    // needed there to measure real height
    myWebView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))

    var counter = 0

    // TODO treatment is busy waiting - but I don't know how to handle it correctly...
    while (myWebView.measuredHeight <= 0) {
        counter ++
        if (counter > 10) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "measuredHeight is still ${myWebView.measuredHeight}")
            Logger.e(TAG, "skipped")

            return
        }

        // sleep and try to measure again
        Logger.e(TAG, "measuredHeight is ${myWebView.measuredHeight}")
        Thread.sleep(200)

        myWebView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))
    }

    Logger.d(TAG, "measuredHeight: ${myWebView.measuredHeight}")
}
```

I have tried to work with `onPageFinished` - but that one is actually invoked (on real device with Android v9/10) around 10ms before `onPageCommitVisible`.

Is there some way without the busy waiting?

============= UPDATE ==============

Even the busy waiting mentioned above is not the solution.

I have from time to time a situation, where the webpage is not processed completely, but is cutted. Updated the logging at the end:

```
Logger.d(TAG, "measuredHeight: ${myWebView.measuredHeight}")

// sleep and try to measure again
Thread.sleep(1000)

myWebView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))
Logger.d(TAG, "measuredHeight: ${myWebView.measuredHeight}")
```

Result is for example:

```
measuredHeight is 826
measuredHeight is 1056
```

This means that something is displayed, height is more than zero, but **it is not yet final**... Any idea?

Comment: onPageLoaded() ?

Comment: Could you be more specific, what should be this `onPageLoaded`, please?

Comment: Then what is onPageFinished?

Comment: By `onPageFinished` I mean https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: I mean about the same.

Comment: So, as I have stated - that one is invoked **before** `onPageCommitVisible`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from the following:

```
myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
```

To the following callback:

```
myWebView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
    override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
```

It looks like this does the trick. `onProgressChanged` is invoked several time, in my case twice with `newProgress=100`. I am starting the *measurement* in the first occurence of value 100 and it seems to work. At least *so far*.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar situation I managed an acceptable solution. I have adapted it to your code. It is about overriding the shouldInterceptRequest method to do the measurement on it. What I have done is in the onPageCommitVisible method I set a value that allows the measurement to be executed. The other variable guarantees that only once the measurement is performed.

```
class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    private val TAG = "CustomWebViewClient"
    private var finishRender = false
    private var measured = false

    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): WebResourceResponse? {
        Log.i(TAG, "shouldInterceptRequest")
        if (finishRender && !measured) {
            measureView(view)
            measured = true
        }
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
    }

    override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
        Log.i(TAG, "onPageCommitVisible")
        finishRender = true
    }

    private fun measureView(view: WebView?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Measuring view")
        view?.measure(
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        )
        Log.i(TAG, "measuredHeight: ${view?.measuredHeight}")
        Log.i(TAG, "measuredWidth: ${view?.measuredWidth}")
    }
}
```

I think it can work as you expect! All the best.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this seems not to work for me. In my code, the `shouldInterceptRequest` is being invoked only once, around 90ms before the invocation of `onPageCommitVisible`. There is no second invocation after the render is finnished.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find another solution to the problem.
If we evaluate the content with the following JS method we can get the height.

The JS evaluate method:

```
    private fun measureContentHeight(webView: WebView) {
        val javascript = """
            (function() {
                var body = document.body;
                var html = document.documentElement;
                var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
                return height;
            })();
        """.trimIndent()

        webView.evaluateJavascript(javascript) { result ->
            val height = result?.toIntOrNull()
            if (height != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Content height: $height")
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to measure content height")
            }
        }
    }
```

The use in Custom WebViewClient:

```
  override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
        measureContentHeight(view!!)
    }
```

All the best!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but seems not to work for me either... getting the *Failed to measure content height*. The result of the `evaluateJavascript` is null.